# Constructing different topology of $S^1$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have a question regarding basic topology.
I ran into an exercise (which I was able to solve, I think) but some general things may still be a bit unclear to me.

The exercise was to show that $X=[0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1$, where we consider the usual Euclidean metric topologies.
Defining $a:X\to S^1$ by $a:t \mapsto (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$, we can see that its inverse is not continuous since any open set of form similar to $[0,\frac 12)$ leads to $a([0,\frac 12))$ being not open due to the troubles with the point $(1,0)$.

However, I was wondering if it is possible to construct a topology on $S^1$ that sets such as $a([0,\frac 12))$ are open.

The question actually boils down to the fact that I'm a bit confused that we can have open sets on $\mathbb{R}$ that are half-open intervals, i.e. including a point that doesn't have any neighboring point at one side, but in a subpart of $\mathbb{R}^2$ this seems to not be the case, or at least not a case that we want to look at in this example.

If there is some major error in my thought process I'm happy to be corrected. Otherwise I would be interested to hear why we can't construct such a topology on $S^1$ or if we could, what would the immediate consequences be.

Comment: Before your question: in general, proving that a specific function is not a homeomorphism doesn't mean that there can't be any homeomorphism between them. So your proof that $[0,1)$ and $S^1$ are not homeomorphic is not correct. The easiest proof is simply noting that one space is compact, while the other one is not.

Comment: That is indeed true, thanks for the remark.

Comment: @Mark Another proof notes that $[0,1)$ has only one non-cutpoint (i.e. $0$)  while in $S^1$ only has non-cutpoints. The number of cutpoints and non-cutpoints is a topological invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a topology on $S^1$ like this: $U\subseteq S^1$ is open if and only if $a^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1)$. It's easy to check that this is indeed a topology, and it turns $a$ into a homeomorphism.